# Are there any MD packages that do proper free energy sampling in the NPT ensemble?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gibbs-free-energy, thermodynamics, statistical-thermodynamics

Statistical Mechanics is the basis of molecular level calculations of properties and averages. Nowadays free energy calculations are fairly "turn-the-crank", which is not necessarily a good thing. It is easy to perform a free energy calculation and get a number.

In the molecular dynamics package GROMACS, for instance, alchemical free energy calculations are only valid if done in the NVT ensemble. This is because GROMACS samples potential energies, thus one can calculate (or press a button on pymbar or another piece of software)

\begin{equation}
    \Delta A = -kT \ln \langle \exp(-\beta \Delta \mathcal{U}) \rangle
\end{equation}

Where $\Delta A$ is the difference in the Helmholtz free energy between two states, $\beta = \frac{1}{kT}$, $\mathcal{U}$ is the difference in sampled potential energy between two states, and $\langle \rangle$ is an ensemble average.

If you run an NPT simulation you must instead sample

\begin{equation}
    \Delta G = -kT \ln \frac{\langle V \exp(-\beta \Delta \mathcal{U}) \rangle}{\langle V \rangle} 
\end{equation}

While it is tempting to say that the volumes cancel so you only need the ensemble average of the NVT Boltzmann factor, this is not at all correct. GROMACS is aware that it is not correctly sampling the NPT and has tucked away a note in the user manual to the effect that for water at 298.15 K the error is small i.e., less than a kilojoule.

1. a kilojoule can make a large difference to an equilibrium constant
2. Chemistry does not happen at only 298.15! if you increase the temperature or density of the solvent (not all of us do water) the error quickly gets out of hand - this is particularly true for ionic liquids.

### Question:

Is this assumption (possibly error in other codes) present in other codes? Are there any MD codes that properly sample the NPT ensemble for free energy?

### Note:

While Godzilla has shown entirely correctly how one *should* sample the free energy in the NPT, neither his equation, or mine, which is equivalent for $\Delta G$, are implemented in GROMACS, and possibly others. I am looking for if any MD programs do implement the proper free energy sampling. They all properly do NPT sampling (I assume), but sampling the free energy is a step above and beyond.

Comment: Luckily I don't yet have the [critic badge](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/7/critic), so I can't ever be blamed for it! It wasn't Godzilla either, because they got the badge in May, but still have only downvoted once. Unless maybe they un-downvoted and re-downvoted. It's one of 57 people that hold the critic badge: Not me, not you, and not Gozilla. A true mystery indeed!

Answer (score 10):

It is straightforward to show that in a typical $NPT$ setting the Zwanzig equation still only depends on the energy difference and not on the volume (here I define $H$ to be the Hamiltonian of each system, respectively and $x$ to represent all variables over phase space):

$$\frac{Z_{B,NPT}}{Z_{A,NPT}} = \int  \int e^{-\beta \Delta H(x)} \frac{e^{-\beta H_A(x)}}{Z_{A,NPT}} e^{-\beta PV} dxdV = \left<e^{-\beta \Delta H}\right>_{A,NPT}$$

so I am not sure where you get this equation from $-$ it seems wrong to me. Of course, you still get $NPT$ contribution in this way, since the exponential averages have to be performed in the isothermal-isobaric ensemble, and these will generally be different to averages obtained in $NVT$ (although in many practical purposes, virtually the same, especially in dense systems that are not near any critical points).

I am not sure which part of the GROMACS manual you are referring to, but I suspect you are talking about the Berendsen barostat. The Berendsen barostat is known to be not rigorous but very good for equilibration (again, for many systems it is practically the same as a rigorous barostat and usually not the limiting error). For a production run you should use the Parrinello-Rahman barostat, which is considered to be rigorous. However, it is deterministic, which can lead to some practical problems regarding non-physical oscillations. This is the "rigorous" barostat implemented in GROMACS and to my knowledge this way of calculating free energies in $NPT$ is completely valid from a theoretical standpoint.

Another rigorous barostat which is also stochastic is the Monte Carlo barostat. Unfortunately, it is only implemented in AMBER and OpenMM and not in GROMACS. As far as I know, NAMD comes with a Nosé-Hoover Langevin piston barostat which is also rigorous. You can see that pretty much every MD engine comes with a Berendsen barostat and a single rigorous barostat and they all use different rigorous barostats.

As a final remark, if you are planning to run simulations at high temperatures, I'd be *much* more worried about the validity of your model, presumably a force field, at these extreme conditions. Also, while it is true that 1 kJ/mol can be considered significant in some cases, there are so many errors when calculating free energies, including force field accuracy, insufficient sampling, estimator convergence (e.g. Zwanzig), or even the fact that you restrict your system to be a tiny box, that I would be much less worried about the impact of the barostat, or indeed the choice of thermodynamic ensemble on my results in most conceivable applications.

Comment: +10. Godzilla is back!

Comment: I've always been here, I am just waiting to prey on molecular dynamics questions :)

Comment: Here's one! https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1523/5

Comment: I saw that one, but I am afraid quantum methods are not my forte - I've never done ab initio MD in my life and I gravitate towards classical MD and free energies more than anything else

Comment: I confess that I don't know *anything* about MD (classical or quantum!) and had no idea what Car-Parinello MD was, but since the paper has 12,000 citations and earned them the Dirac Medal, I decided to learn it and explain it in that answer. While doing so I also learned what Born-Oppenheimer MD was (basically the same thing but with re-calculating the electronic ground state at each MD step rather than evolving it using the "fictitious dynamics") but I'm a believer in answering only once for each question, and giving others a chance (for now).

Comment: Also, the very last part of your expression is correct where H = Enthalpy. This is not potential energy. If you do the integration, you get my expression. This is incredibly well known in Monte Carlo where chemical potentials are routinely calculated. Molecular Dynamics seem to miss this all the time. There is literature going back to the 80's on chemical potential calculations.

Comment: This might be related to the Helmholtz/Gibbs discussion: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1501/5. The person that answered claimed not to be an expert though, so maybe @Charlie can give a better answer distinguishing Helmholtz from Gibbs there?

Comment: This is not Helmholtz free energy but Gibbs free energy and this is an equation which can be found in any introductory statistical mechanics textbook, so I am not sure what you mean by this statement. Also, I define H to be the Hamiltonian, not the enthalpy. Finally, you can't "just do the integration", because the Hamiltonian is also implicitly and non-trivially dependent on the volume and the volume integration is part of the expectation value, i.e. you can only do it numerically with sampling. That being said, I would be interested to read any Monte Carlo references you mentioned.

Comment: Just to clarify: the $\int (...) e^{-\beta PV}dV$ part is absorbed into the $\left<(...)\right>_{NPT}$ part and that's the job of the barostat: to draw volumes from a correct distribution. With a Monte Carlo barostat, you do get a term involving $P\Delta V$ in your acceptance criterion, but that is still a part of the barostat, and not of the free energy estimator.

Comment: Ah, I just realised that you are interested in changing the number of particles, while the Hamiltonians I have used in the derivation assume the same number of particles. I think that if you play around with my equation and assume that one of the particles is transformed into a dummy particle you can derive yours, so I think both are correct in your setting and yours looks more practical. In any case, it should be possible to calculate whatever you want rigorously using the $NPT$ ensemble average as long as you have a valid barostat, no?

Comment: Your equation is correct @Godzilla123, my question is if it is implemented in software. It is not implemented in GROMACS. Gromacs does not calculate the difference in enthalpy and put that in the boltzmann factor. If you take your equation, you get mine with manipulation. Neither is wrong. My question is if there is software doing this proper sampling - they leave out the V terms in my equation, and the PV terms in yours. The issue is not the Barostat :)

Comment: To be clear - sampling in the NPT is not an issue. MD programs shake the box just fine and tend to sample phase space "correctly". However, to sample free energy correctly, one must sample both volume and potential energy and include both in the analysis, using either mine or yours.

Comment: Also to note: My formula is only for the residual contribution, or intrinsic. It does not include the ideal gas contribution.

Comment: Ah, I think I am getting your problem now. What I would do is that after I perform the free energy perturbation, I would go to the energy.xvg file, which contains all the modified $\Delta U$s and also the $PV$ term for each snapshot. Then I would read the file using a parser (for example alchemlyb) and modify each (reduced) $\Delta u$ to $\Delta u - \ln V + \ln\left<V\right>$ (you just need to make sure you are using the correct volumes for each $\Delta u$). And then I would pass these modified $\Delta u$s to pymbar and let it do its magic. Would that not work?

Comment: @Godzilla123 I get how to fix it, there is an easier way using thermodynamics - you can convert between Helhholtz and Gibbs using the compressibility factor :) - I am just curious if there are any programs that actually just do it right, from the beginning, for the user. Not many users are as knowledgable as you, or even aware of the problem, on the offcase they are knowledgeable enough.

Comment: I see, I am afraid I don't know enough to answer that then. I always classed the actual free energy calculation as the analysis step and I don't really expect MD engines to do that for us. In a way GROMACS is the MD engine which has the most analysis capabilities (which I always considered to be a bonus, rather than necessity) so if it doesn't do it properly then I wouldn't expect most other engines to do that either. As far as I know, AMBER and NAMD are one of the few other free MD engines with adequate free energy capabilities so that's where I would search for a solution to your problem...

Comment: @Godzilla123 I tend to agree with you. MD is just a borderline trivial algorithm for shaking molecules, the sampling is the area of active research, however, programs advertise that they can do free energy calculations. This being the case, it would be nice if they did them correctly. It is hard to do accurate science when everyone is using Helmholtz free energies in place of Gibbs without even knowing it.